# Presentations of quantum general linear groups

Tags: quantum-groups

Are there some references which write presentations of quantum general linear groups explicitly? For example, what are generators and relations for $U_q(gl_2)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't most sources define $U_q\left(\mathfrak{gl}_n\right)$ via generators and relations? I thought doing it in any other way would be way too difficult.

Comment: Specifically for $U_q\left(\mathfrak{gl}_2\right)$, a neat nonstandard presentation was found by Ito, Terwilliger and Weng: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507477v1

Answer (score 1):

We can find a presentation in [NONCOMMUTATIVE SYMMETRIC FUNCTIONS V: A DEGENERATE VERSION OF $U_q(gl_N)$](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00018542/document).